# Getting a custom prompt box to return true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I am attempting to code a custom javascript confirmation box. At the click of the [OK] button, the dialog box should a true value and at the click of the [CANCEL] button, the dialog box should return a false value. However, it seems that the alert box fires prematurely, and that when I click the buttons, nothing happens.

```
function test() {

var btn1 = "<br><br><input type='button' class='button' value='OK' onclick='function(){ return true}'>"
var btn2 = "<br><br><input type='button' class='button' value='CANCEL' onclick='function(){ return false}'>"

var x = ShowDialog(false,"Test",btn1 + btn2)

alert(x)

}
```

Ive made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avbvj98a/1/):

Comment: your code is completely wrong , you have to separate your HTML and Javascript code please  read basic article of javascript and html here
http://www.w3schools.com/ its realy help you to solve your problems quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't have a custom dialog in javascript that blocks execution the way `alert` does. Actually the one you're trying to implement is `confirm()`. It is a system function provided by browser. It returns `true` or `false` depending on which button was clicked.

However the only way you can do your custom popup using html is to do it asynchronously. Thus you should call `ShowDialog` and provide a callback to it. It will be called when user clicks one of the buttons. Any code that exists after call to `ShowDialog` will be called immediately. And all code that you want to process the result of the dialog should be placed inside the callback

```
var btn1 = "<br><br><input type='button' class='button' value='OK' x-data='true'>"
var btn2 = "<br><br><input type='button' class='button' value='CANCEL' x-data='false'>"
ShowDialog(false, "Test", btn1 + btn2, undefined, function(result){
    alert(result)
})

function ShowDialog(modal, title, text, colour, callback) {
    ...
    $('input', '#dialog_text').click(function(){
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback($(this).attr('x-data'));
        }
        HideDialog();
    });
}
```

[Edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Grety/avbvj98a/2/)